# additional jquery not works in datatable pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have `Datatable` and jquery plugin that deletes row of this data table

Jquery Code :

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".delete-ajax").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            recordId = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(recordId);
            var requestAdress = '{!! route("admin.area.cities.destroy", ":id") !!}';
            requestAdress = requestAdress.replace(':id', recordId);
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "delete"
                , url: requestAdress
                , date: {
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                    "id": recordId
                },
                success: function () {
                    $('tr#' + recordId).fadeOut(300, 'linear');
                }
            }, "json");

            });
 });
```

Code work's fine but whenever i change page in `datatable` pagination jquery plugin. This Click doesn't work any more.

Datatable website: http://datatables.net

Comment: how about not using the $(document).ready function. what about the event that triggers the pagination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of .live() is depreciated now. Use event delegation :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("click",".delete-ajax", function (e) { // updated ths line
            e.preventDefault();
            recordId = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(recordId);
            var requestAdress = '{!! route("admin.area.cities.destroy", ":id") !!}';
            requestAdress = requestAdress.replace(':id', recordId);
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "delete"
                , url: requestAdress
                , date: {
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                    "id": recordId
                },
                success: function () {
                    $('tr#' + recordId).fadeOut(300, 'linear');
                }
            }, "json");

            });
 });
```

Check out [Live Removed](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed)